# Transforming DOM elements to React components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have some HTML (origin is markdown), and it contain some custom markup. Right now I use jQuery to transform the custom markup, but it would be nice to transform the DOM elements to React components (similar to Angular directives).

Here is a contrived example:

```
<!-- input -->
<question>What is the meaning of life?</question>

<!-- output -->
<div class="Question">
   <strong>What is the meaning of life?</strong>
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

I created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arve0/zh2rvv2h/3/) which does the transformation. I took this approach:

```
let questions = $("question");

class Question extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Question">
        <strong>{this.props.text}</strong>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let i = 0;
$.map(questions, question => {
  $(question).replaceWith(`<div id="question${i}"></div>`)
  let replaced = document.getElementById(`question${i}`);
  ReactDOM.render(<Question text={question.innerText} />, replaced)
  ++i;
})
```

As I just naively thought this out, I tried to find out if others had done similar approaches, but was not able to find anything.

Is this a bad idea? Is there any best practices for transforming DOM (or strings) to React components?

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: Beacause the origin is a string (markdown). The custom markup adds interactivity, like showing/hiding some other elements on clicking/correct answer/etc. Generally altering the state (the progression in a lesson). I would like to capture the state, such that the user can pick up where he left upon returning to the lesson.

Comment: Relevant: http://addyosmani.com/blog/component-interop-with-react-and-custom-elements/ and https://github.com/PixelsCommander/ReactiveElements/